# Why does my ssh session terminate immediately?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a debian machine, where I have difficulties to log into via ssh.  Executing commands on the server over ssh is no problem -- just I get no prompt, but the connection is terminated again:

```
> ssh root@192.168.2.109
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-kirkwood #1 Sun May 6 16:57:51 UTC 2012 armv5tel

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Apr 17 21:54:34 2013 from 192.168.2.101
Connection to 192.168.2.109 closed.
```

As I said, running command works well:

```
> ssh root@192.168.2.109 cat /etc/bash.bashrc
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

# To enable the settings / commands in this file for login shells as well,
# this file has to be sourced in /etc/profile.

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, overwrite the one in /etc/profile)
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '

# Commented out, don't overwrite xterm -T "title" -n "icontitle" by default.
# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
#case "$TERM" in
#xterm*|rxvt*)
#    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"'
#    ;;
#*)
#    ;;
#esac

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#fi

# if the command-not-found package is installed, use it
if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found -o -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
        function command_not_found_handle {
                # check because c-n-f could've been removed in the meantime
                if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                elif [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found ]; then
                   /usr/bin/python /usr/share/command-not-found -- $1
                   return $?
                else
                   return 127
                fi
        }
fi
```

(I can also run a crippled bash with `ssh root@192.168.2.109 bash`.)

I am attaching the verbose session output here:

```
> ssh -vvv root@192.168.2.109
OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/andreas/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.2.109 [192.168.2.109] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/andreas/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/andreas/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.2.109" from file "/home/andreas/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/andreas/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 120/256
debug2: bits set: 523/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 1b:08:38:7d:37:05:03:42:f2:59:a1:43:82:1d:84:b6
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.2.109" from file "/home/andreas/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/andreas/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.2.109' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/andreas/.ssh/known_hosts:26
debug2: bits set: 522/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/andreas/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f4d7356b2e0)
debug2: key: /home/andreas/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/andreas/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/andreas/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp 47:7c:14:dd:25:54:14:0d:d8:cf:c5:24:44:d4:7b:c2
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA 47:7c:14:dd:25:54:14:0d:d8:cf:c5:24:44:d4:7b:c2
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 192.168.2.109 ([192.168.2.109]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env GPG_AGENT_INFO
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_COOKIE
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env TMUX
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env ANDROID_SDK
debug1: Sending env LANG = de_DE.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env TMUX_PANE
debug3: Ignored env PS1
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWPATH
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Linux debian 2.6.32-5-kirkwood #1 Sun May 6 16:57:51 UTC 2012 armv5tel

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Wed Apr 17 21:55:06 2013 from 192.168.2.101
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-signal reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Connection to 192.168.2.109 closed.
Transferred: sent 3072, received 2760 bytes, in 0.0 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 72154.8, received 64826.6
debug1: Exit status -1
```

What's going on here?

EDIT:
Here is my ~/.bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
```

And my ~/.profile

```
# ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi
```

And finally the /etc/profile:

```
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Comment: Can you cat your own ~/bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, and so on and see if they are causing the issue? Made any changes to shell initialisation files recently?

Comment: @tink Thanks for following this up.  I only have ~/.bashrc and ~/.profile.  See the edit for the contents.  I have not done any edit -- this has been the situation right from the install.  (The machine is a pogoplug, if that is of interest)

Comment: Can you get at the server logs? In this case, probably /var/log/messages, or /var/log/auth.log

Comment: @JennyD No, I can not -- these files are missing.  `ls /var/log` gives me only `alternatives.log
apt
boot
bootstrap.log
btmp
dmesg
dmesg.0
dmesg.1.gz
dmesg.2.gz
dmesg.3.gz
dmesg.4.gz
dpkg.log
faillog
fsck
lastlog
wtmp`

Answer (score 6):

Check `/etc/passwd` and make sure your user doesn't have something like `/sbin/nologin` set as the login shell (last field of the record); if so, change it to `/bin/bash` or similar, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks.  But `/etc/passwd` looks good (I think):  `ssh root@192.168.2.109 cat /etc/passwd | head -n 1` gives `root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash`

Comment: You're logging in as root?  Check that root logins are not disabled in your config.  Can you login as other users?

Comment: If they were disabled the "cat something" wouldn't work.

Comment: Also, check your `/etc/profile` and `.bash_profile` for errors.

Comment: @pgs root logins are allowed and the situation is the same for other users.  See the edit for more config files.

Comment: @tink: no, you can run commands via SSH on an account which can't log in -- sshd just launches the specified command, instead of the shell specified in /etc/passwd. (That's why the connection terminates when the command finishes.) That said, @Andreas, it looks like /etc/passwd is fine; what happens when you SSH in as another user, then try to `su` to root? It really sounds like the specific problem you're having is with starting a login shell for root ('ssh root@... bash' doesn't start bash as a login shell, so it doesn't read .profile &c.), but I can't tell the problem by reading the files.

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with the Pogoplug environment, but here's a blog post from someone who is, and maybe that'll help: http://mehl.co/articles/configuring_ssh_on_the_pogoplug/index.html

Comment: @AaronMiller Thanks for the pointers.  The problem does not seem to be specific for the root user as it is the same for other users.  Also the link you gave does not seem to have my problem, as the guy could log into the device from the beginning, which I could not.  But strangely enough, I did basically what that guy did to get debian installed on the pogoplug.

Comment: +1 on this because my ReadyNAS had /bin/false set for non-root users.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can run `ssh root@192.168.2.109 bash`, try:

- `ssh root@192.168.2.109 bash -l` to get bash to behave as a login shell, i.e. read .profile instead of .bashrc and so on.
- `ssh -t root@192.168.2.109 bash` (if the above works, use `bash -l` instead) to get a PTY allocated.

If both work, you may have `UseLogin` set to true in `/etc/sshd.config`; if so, turn it off. If that fixes the problem, you could try to figure out what `/bin/login` is doing that doesn't work, or you could ignore it, it adds no value.

If only the latter works (without the `-l` to bash), there's a startup file problem; bash runs `/etc/profile` (this will run `/etc/bash.bashrc`, which you didn't post, and source `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` - I don't expect anything weird there if you haven't changed them), then the first it finds of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile` - the latter looks fine, but if either of the former exists, that will be used instead. Note that any of these may source other scripts that could exit out.

If only the former works, then despite what the ssh output is saying, there's a problem allocating a PTY - but that's usually a permission problem, which wouldn't affect root.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  None of them worked (neither bash -l nor ssh -t).  By now I decided to go for a re-install.  In the end that was cheaper than the continued hunt for the cause of the error.